# Sonarqube 5 File not found exception

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

After updating to sonarqube 5.0 we can not analyze our multimodule project on windows anymore.

The problem seems to be that the class PhasesSumUpTimeProfiler (org.sonar.batch.profiling) uses the moduleKey as part of the fileame to store a dump file and this can have special characters.

```
String fileName = module.getKey() + "-profiler.properties";
```

The problem is now that the module key contains a colon (:) character. 
Is there a workarround. How can we change the module key to not be concated with a colon character.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to store profiler output: D:\jenkins_slave\workspace\ci-build-win-fast-sonar-ssd-64\build\.sonar\profiling\ch.imagic:ims:acquisition-profiler.properties
at org.sonar.batch.profiling.PhasesSumUpTimeProfiler.dumpToFile(PhasesSumUpTimeProfiler.java:160)
at org.sonar.batch.profiling.PhasesSumUpTimeProfiler.onProjectAnalysis(PhasesSumUpTimeProfiler.java:123)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.ProjectAnalysisEvent.dispatch(ProjectAnalysisEvent.java:42)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.ProjectAnalysisEvent.dispatch(ProjectAnalysisEvent.java:25)
at org.sonar.batch.events.EventBus.doFireEvent(EventBus.java:49)
at org.sonar.batch.events.EventBus.fireEvent(EventBus.java:43)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:139)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:222)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:235)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:230)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:228)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:223)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:65)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:52)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:128)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:171)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
... 63 more

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\jenkins_slave\workspace\ci-build-win-fast-sonar-ssd-64\build\.sonar\profiling\ch.imagic:ims:acquisition-profiler.properties (Die Syntax für den Dateinamen, Verzeichnisnamen oder die Datenträgerbezeichnung ist falsch)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
at org.sonar.batch.profiling.PhasesSumUpTimeProfiler.dumpToFile(PhasesSumUpTimeProfiler.java:156)
... 92 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, this is a bug and we'll fix this in SonarQube 5.1: [SONAR-6190](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-6190).

Meantime, you can't use the profiling mode - unfortunately.

Thanks for reporting this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I was able to change the key and there remove the colon : character.